# SwiftUI .sheet issues

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been working on an app recently, and in the App, I use an ImagePicker in order to post images. I have my `TabBarView` below, and I have a button that should present a sheet with the ImagePicker, but the sheet is not being presented. Here, I just replaced the image picker with some text in order to ensure the issue isn't with the ImagePicker. I know the problem is probably trivial, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

- I took out a bunch of the TabBarView out here, so if you need more of the code, just let me know.

  ```
  struct TabBarView: View {


    @State var pickAnImage: Bool = false
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State var showCameraPicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: UIImage?

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                Spacer()
                if self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" {
                    HomeView2(dataHandler: dataHandler)
                } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "profile" {
                    ProfileView()
                }
                else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "new-entry" {
                    NewEntryView(image: self.image)
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "explore" {
                    ExploreView()
                }else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "settings" {
                    SettingsView()
                }
                Spacer()
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(yellow)
                                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .padding(20)
                                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            self.viewRouter.currentView = "home"
                            self.showImagePicker.toggle()
                            self.pickAnImage.toggle()
                            self.showPopUp = false

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            .sheet(isPresented: self.$pickAnImage, content: {
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("World!!")
                }
            })

        }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Sheet is working fine. What error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, and there isn't an error, it just doesn't pop up. Maybe its an XCode bug?

Comment: The code runs for me and if I press the yellow circle, the sheet appears. Tested on Xcode 12.2. Maybe your code example above doesn't represent your example

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with my full code. Here is the file, thank you for your help so far! https://github.com/sauravkumr/sheetIssue

Comment: Still working for me.. may I ask why you use foregroundColor(yellow). It is not compiling for me. Always have to change to foregroundColor(.yellow). Or did you declare yellow somewhere?

Comment: Yep, my apologies, I did set a custom yellow color declared elseware. I assume the problem is with my computer, I'll restart and try again.

Comment: Hmmm still not working, maybe I will update my computer or wait for a new XCode update.